# UITableViewCell mysteriously changing heights

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I have a xib with an `UITableView` (style: grouped), and a few `UITableViewCells` also on the xib connected as an outlet collection.

I return these cells from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in a fashion very similar to what is described in the [Table View Programming Guide (The Technique for Static Row Content)](http://goo.gl/ZgRiK).

Then I have another `IBOutlet` cell, with a different height, and a button that toggles a flag and reloads always the same row (`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`).

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` for that exact row returns either one of the normal cells from the outlet collection or that special cell (depending on the flag).

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` also takes the height of the appropriate cell and returns it using the same 'logic', I've NSLogged it to death;

Now what happens is each time I press the button, the first and last row add one pixel to their heights! Anyone can think what's happening?

I uploaded a sample project with just this: http://www.mediafire.com/?sc22v0c6w11b4l6

Answer (score 1):

Replacing:

```
return (UIView *)[self.cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] bounds].size.height;
```

by

```
return 30;
```

Fixes your problem.

I think that the redraw of your larger cell modifies the whole table size, and for some reason recomputes the first and last cells to higher size.

Comment: yes, thanks, I just discovered the same thing. however this is just a small test case for a real project with lots of cells with custom heights. If this was the solution (which might be, implying a bug report is in order, perhaps?), I imagine I'd have to store each of the initial heights somewhere and reuse those, or at least ask for the case when the returned height is for the first or the last row...

Comment: Why dont you use Storyboards and custom cells that way?

Comment: can't use storyboards, client asked for iOS 4.x compatibility :/

Comment: Are you allowed to set a fixed size inside the XIB definition for the other rows?

Comment: I did some tests, apparently, the reloadRowsAtIndexPaths is causing the table to recompute height of some rows.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has happened only when your tableViewStyle is grouped... so you can either use plain style or return hardcode value

```
if (indexPath.row == kBigCellRowNum && self.showTheBigCell){

    return self.bigCell.frame.size.height;

}

else{

    return 44;

}
```